# Granular control of access rights and authorization structures in MS Teams in connection with sharepoint online websitesites

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams

Actually i am searching for ways to implement a more granulary method to control the access structures in sharepoint websites.

**Basically i am dealing with this kind of structure:**

I´ve got an MS Teams environment, which basically has three different user-types to control the access structure ("owners", "members" and "guests"). In the background the MS Teams environment is a connected with a sharepoint file storage structure.

Inside this connected sharepoint structure, there is a bunch of sharepoint websitesites.
As far as i know, the sharepoint structure completely inherits the access / authorization structures from the MS Teams environment (=the three described user roles).

**Is there any way to make the access structures more granulary for sharepoint websitesites?**

There are 20 websitesites. Every connected user with the role "guest" can view the whole site content. Is there any way to make the access structures more granulary?

E.g. some of the users with the role "guest" should only be enabled to see 5/20 of the sharepoint websitesites, because they don´t pay for the content (but should have access to the other pages).

As far as i know, in older sharepoint versions, there was a way to define something like user groups.

If you need more information of any kind, please let me know and I will adapt the description accordingly.